# Prevent to access to page by index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I use clean URLs in my site and I want to prevent access to my page when a user write index.php in URL! I also have `index.php` in my form that has POST method!

Is there any way I can use something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  = GET [AND] %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} = index.php
Redirect 301 / http://example.com/
```

Is this code correct ?

**EDIT**

I use this but it seems it fall in infinity loop !

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  ^GET$ 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} ^index.php
Redirect 301 / http://www.XXXXXXXXX.net/
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  ^GET$
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} ^index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://XXXXX.COM/ [R=301]
```

Comment: `=GET` and `=index.php` could be used instead of `^GET$` and `^index.php` respectively ([ref.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)).

Comment: @jensgram Didn't know that! Does =GET only match GET, or also GETIT?

Comment: It performs a lexicographically equal comparison on the two strings, so `=GET` matches `GET` and nothing else (identical to `^GET$`.

Comment: Ah ok, i was just wondering because in your first comment you said it matches ^GET$ and ^index.php, but you probably mean ^index.php$ then :) Thanks for the heads-up btw!

Comment: @Tom Knapen Yes, good catch. `=index.php` is not identical to `^index.php` (but to `^index.php$`). My bad.

Comment: To what page do you want the user to be redirected to? You can't redirect him to the index.php page since the request would use the GET method, which will cause an infinite loop.

Comment: i want to prevent user access to my page by this url http://www.XXXXX.com/index.php?XXXXXXX when i use clean url

Comment: @hamid check my answer, I've edited it to what I believe is you are asking